# Getting lowest hierarchy child in join select using closure table

Tags: mysql, sql, tree, hierarchical-data, transitive-closure-table

I have a closure table HIERARCHY

```
ancestor | descendant | depth
100      | 100        | 0
2        | 100        | 1
3        | 100        | 2
4        | 100        | 3
```

and a joined table PROPERTIES

```
id       | key        | value
4        | action     | DEFAULT
4        | duration   | PT1H
100      | action     | OVERRIDE
100      | duration   | PT1M
```

I can get the whole sub-tree using the query

```
  SELECT id, key, value
    FROM hierarchy, properties
   WHERE id = ancestor
     AND descendant = 100
ORDER BY depth
```

What would be the simplest/fastest way to get the *lowest* hierarchy member?, ie. having `min(depth)`

```
100      | action     | OVERRIDE
100      | duration   | PT1M
```

I still need to keep the hierarchy, meaning that if `100` isn't found in the query, `4` would show up.

In other words, I'm trying to find all the rows of the tree member with the lowest depth possible, possibly without duplicating the query in the `WHERE` clause

The database is the currently full-released mysql, ie. 5.7

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ce317/16

```
With A as(
    Select 
      id, _key, value, depth
    From 
      hierarchy
    Join
      properties
    On id = ancestor And descendant = 100
    ) 
Select id, _key, value from A
Where depth = (select min(depth) from A)
```

For MySQL, use a temp table...

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE A AS 
(
    Select 
      id, _key, value, depth
    From 
      hierarchy
    Join
      properties
    On id = ancestor And descendant = 100
); 
Select id, _key, value from A
Where depth = (select min(depth) from A);
```

Or, hope that MySQL will cache ... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2350e/1

```
Select id, _key, value
From
(
    Select id, _key, value, depth From hierarchy Join properties On id = ancestor And descendant = 100
) B
Join
    (
      Select min(A.depth) min
      From
      (
        Select id, _key, value, depth From hierarchy Join properties On id = ancestor And descendant = 100
      ) A
    )C
On
  B.depth = C.min
```

About cache. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44266/does-mysql-cache-queries

Comment: This would be great, but so far mysql still doesn't support common table expressions. I'll update the question so it's more clear.

Comment: Let us translate it.

Comment: Thought so - I'm looking for a simpler way than using the same query twice (ie. join or a subquery) and temporary table would a pain to use as it's not just a query. Guess I'll have to wait for mysql 8.